# Order of self-invoking function in page load events - javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onload, self-invoking-function

I'm looking to find out the order at which a self-invoking js function takes place in terms of the order of events in a page load. I've been googling all over for an answer to this but haven't found anything definitive.

And as for what this actually applies to, I'm adjusting the height of an outer element based on the height of one of it's inner elements (which will vary depending on length of text and screen width)

```
    var text_elem = document.getElementById('text_elem');
    var textElemHeight = text_elem.offsetHeight;
    var newBkgdHeight = 96 + textElemHeight;
    document.getElementById('background').style.height = newBkgdHeight + "px";
```

as of now this block is being executed in a self-invoked function as opposed to an onload event since with an onload event there's a weird effect where the height adjusts a second or 2 after the page has loaded, but just wanted to be sure that using a self-invoked function is safe and that there's no chance of the code within it being executed before the HTML DOM loads.

EDIT:

Just as a note, this is working properly using a self-invoking function or IIFE, I just want to make sure it's safe and will consistently work, and be able to explain this better to a colleague if it is.

Here is the relevant code for this situation:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #background {
        height: 150px;
    }
</style>
......
......
<div id="background">
   <div id="text_elem">
      ${text loaded from somewhere else}
   </div>
</div>
......
......
<script>
(function() {
    var text_elem = document.getElementById('text_elem');
    var textElemHeight = text_elem.offsetHeight;
    var newBkgdHeight = 96 + textElemHeight;
    document.getElementById('background').style.height = newBkgdHeight + "px";
})();
</script>
```

Comment: if the IIFE is inline, not in any sort of event handler, then it executes immediately and does not wait for DOM load events

Comment: It runs when it is reached. Biggest  difference is reading heights can change based on the content of the element. So you might get the wrong values.

Comment: Please post the code with the self-invoking function.

Comment: Seems like what you are doing could be done with pure CSS with no need for JavaScript. But can not fully tell since no HTML was provided.

Comment: Use the correct terminology ***Immediately Invoked** Function Expression* (instead of "self-executing function") and the question vanishes :-)

Comment: epascarello, how so? Is there anyway in pure CSS to adjust the height of the background element based on the height of it's inner element?

Comment: There's a good pattern of putting script tags at the bottom of the body of the document, because since the browser parses the HTML document synchronously (except when script tags are intentionally deferred) by the time the browser reads the script tag, the rest of the document has been loaded. Typically.

Comment: How would it not be the height of the content if it is the parent? Seems like you are just adding 96px of padding to it. `#background {
        min-height: 150px;
        padding: 48px 0;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IIFE will execute as soon as the `<script>` block containing it is loaded.

Since it's located at the end of the HTML, it will be executed after all the earlier HTML is loaded into the DOM.

The execution time is no different than if you hadn't put it in an IIFE at all, but just wrote it as top-level JavaScript code. The only difference from putting it in an IIFE is that the variables are local rather than global.